# Why is Discourse running so slowly?

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, vagrant, discourse

I'm not sure which link in the chain is causing the problem. I just finished setting up Discourse on Vagrant on a Windows machine. Everything seems to be working fine, except that it took a good 86000ms (a minute and a half!) for Discourse to load in the browser. Something tells me that it's not supposed to be that slow. Where can I look for problems that might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the most relevant discussion on the forum.

http://meta.discourse.org/t/development-mode-super-slow/2179

Make sure you have allocated enough resources in the virtual machine.

You can also try this in the development configs

```
#config/environments/development.rb

config.cache_classes = true
```

This made a huge difference to my render time. From 8 minutes to 30 seconds. Still a bit slow though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my VM when testing Discourse. What you actually have to do is change a config setting for WEBrick. Look for your WEBrick config which is usually in `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.3/webrick/config.rb` yours could be different, it all depends on your particular setup.

Then change this line

```
:DoNotReverseLookup => nil,
```

to this

```
:DoNotReverseLookup => true,
```

Restart WEBrick and you should be good to go.